# Block in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My view:

```
<%= form_tag(rate_url) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :prod_id, params[:product_id] %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :rating_set_id, params[:rating_set_id] %>
  <span class = "heading"> Recommendations </span>
  <div><%= submit_tag 'Submit Ratings', :class => " btn right" %></div>
  <span id = "rate_more_link">
    <%= link_to "Rate More Products", products_path(:rating_set_id => params[:rating_set_id])%>
  </span>
  <br/>
  <div id ="prods_container">
  <% @recommendations.each do |rec| %>
    <% url_raw = URI.parse("url_to_parse") %>
    <% url = Net::HTTP.get_response(url_raw).body %>
    <% if url.empty? %>
      <% @title          = "Product Unavailable via API" %>
      <% @url            = "#{rec.wmt_id}" %>
      <% @cover_img      = "_180X180.jpg" %>
      <% @price          = "Product Unavailable via API" %>
    <% else %>
      <% begin %>
        <% @response1  = JSON.parse(url) %>
        <% @title          = @response1["ProductName"]%>
        <% @url            = "{@response1["ProductUrl"]}"%>
        <% @cover_img      = @response1["ImagePath"]%>
        <% @price          = @response1["currentItemPrice"]%>
      <% rescue %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <div id ="prod">
      <span class = "radio_button">
        <%= hidden_field_tag "recommendation_ratings[#{rec.id}][recommendation_id]", rec.id %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "recommendation_ratings[#{rec.id}][rating]", '3'%> Good
        <%= radio_button_tag "recommendation_ratings[#{rec.id}][rating]", '2'%> Fair
        <%= radio_button_tag "recommendation_ratings[#{rec.id}][rating]", '1'%> Bad
        <%= radio_button_tag "recommendation_ratings[#{rec.id}][rating]", '0'%> N/A
      </span>
    <div>
      <a href='<%= @url %>' target="_blank">
        <img src='<%= @cover_img  %>' class='product_image_rec_table'></img>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class = "rec-desc">
      <div class = "small"><b>Wmt ID: </b><%= rec.wmt_id  %></div>  
      <div class = "small"><b>Title: </b><%= @title  %></div>
      <div class = "small"><b>Price: </b>$<%= @price  %></div>
      <div class = "em">
        <b>Current Rating: </b>
        <% rec.ratings.each do |rating_phin| %>
          <%= rating_phin.label %>
        <% end %></div>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <div id="rec_note_text">
        <%= text_field_tag "recommendation_ratings[#{rec.id}][notes]", "#{rec.notes}" ,:id => "rec_note_text", :placeholder => 'Enter Notes..'%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm trying to move the `<% end %>` from the `Current Rating` block to the end so that I can call the `rating_phin` variable in my `text_field_tag`, however when I move the `<% end %>` to the end of my view, everything after the `Current Rating` block is not being rendered. What am I doing wrong? How can I update the `rating_phin.notes` instead of `rec.notes` in my `text_field_tag` at the end of my view?

Comment: For now you should swap last two lines. To find broken part try to remove some parts until it start to work and then move them back one by one.

Comment: This example would benefit *considerably* by creating a helper method to manage a lot of the perplexingly verbose variable assignment that's going on in here.

Answer (score 0):

That `rating_phin` variable only exists within the scope of that `each` loop.

If you require it later, you will have to loop again:

```
<div id="rec_note_text">
  <% rec.ratings.each do |rating_phin| %>
    <%= text_field_tag "recommendation_ratings[#{rec.id}][notes]", "#{rec.notes}" ,:id => "rec_note_text", :placeholder => 'Enter Notes..'%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why you would expect that moving the `<% end %>` tag would be the right thing to do.

If you're getting lost inside of ERB, which is not especially difficult considering how fussy and convoluted HTML can get, especially when there's live Ruby in it, you might want to try [HAML](http://haml.info/). It would reduce this down to about half the number of lines and remove a lot of the `<% %>` and closing tag debris that tends to make ERB hard to read.

Comment: Adding another block around my `text_field_tag` like you suggest causes the text field not to be rendered.

Comment: If it renders something in the first loop, it should render in the second case. If not, maybe something else is broken.

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I just add the block around the `text_field_tag`, even without calling the variable, it causes the text field tag not to be rendered.